# ASP MVC Editing Certain Entities in Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

If I have a website where I can create entities as defined in the following model:

```
public partial class Component
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public string ManufacturerLink { get; set; }
    public string Datasheet { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I'd like to be able to edit this entity from my website, and I think I got most of it in order, as I am able to edit the fields I want (all, except the Id).

My problem is, when I try to make changes to it, the Id gets set to 0, which will always just update the row in the database table with Id 0. How do I persist the Id from the entity I want to change?

This is my Edit view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Edit", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Component</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Info, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Info, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Info, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @{
                var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image);
                var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
            }

            <img src="@imgSrc" height="300px" width="300px" alt="No image to display." />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManufacturerLink, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ManufacturerLink, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManufacturerLink, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Datasheet, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Datasheet, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Datasheet, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save changes" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

This is my action method in the controller that gets called when clicking on the 'Save changes' input button:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Component component)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            componentRepository.UpdateComponent(component);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", component.Id);
        }
        return View("Index", component);
    }
```

This is UpdateComponent from the repository:

```
    public void UpdateComponent(Component component)
    {
        Component comp = mContext.Components.Find(component.Id);

        if (comp != null)
        {
            comp.Name = component.Name;
            comp.Info = component.Info;
            comp.Datasheet = component.Datasheet;
            comp.ManufacturerLink = component.ManufacturerLink;
        }
        mContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Hello, u should try to add `@Html.HiddenFor( model => model.Id)` to your html page.

Comment: FWIW, you should also use an InputModel instead of directly binding to your Entity Framework model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a hidden field in the form you post that would hold the value of Id.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model=> model.Id)
```

You could place this anywhere **inside** the form you post.

> Why this is happening?

When you post your form and the time of model data binding comes, since there isn't any value in the form you post for the `Id`, the `Id` takes it's default value, which is 0.

Comment: Of course! It would have been easy to check if it was because a lack of values in the form, but I didn't even think about that. Thanks!

Comment: @Khaine775 you are welcome dude. I am glad that I helped :)